# query_string and range at the same time

Tags: rest, elasticsearch

How is it possible to have both `query_string` and `range` in the same query?

I am sending this to `/myindex/mytype/_search/?search_type=count`:

```
 {"query": {"query_string": {"query": "field1:value1"},
            "range": {"time": {"gt": "2014-11-01T00:00:00Z",
                               "lte": "2014-11-01T03:00:00Z"}}},
  "aggs": {"counts": {"date_histogram": {"field": "time",
                                         "interval": "minute"}}}}
```

But ES gives me this error:

```
ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but got START_OBJECT \"range\"];
```

If I remove either `range` or `query_string`, it works just fine, but without the much needed filtering :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From what you are saying, it seems you want to combine multiple queries to reduce the scope on which you are computing aggregations.

First, this can be achieved using a `bool` query ([documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#query-dsl-bool-query)) that lets you decide if a document must match both queries (see the `must` clause) or at least one of the queries (see `should` clause).

Let's say you want your result documents to match **both** queries, the syntax will be :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            ...
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            ...
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This will work, but this not the optimal way to query. It could be optimized as your `range` query has an equivalent filter.

Using the filter version will be generally faster, as it will skip the score computation, and will hit the cache for most of the filter types (more information about the [differences between queries and filters here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_queries_and_filters.html#_queries_and_filters)).

However, a filter can't be used directly in the `query` attribute, you have to wrap it in a `filtered` query which has two attributes :

- `query` : the query to be filtered
- `filter` : the filter to combine with your query

Finally, you'll have a query like this one :

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "field1:value1"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "time": {
            "gt": "2014-11-01T00:00:00Z",
            "lte": "2014-11-01T03:00:00Z"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "counts": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "time",
        "interval": "minute"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked!  On a side note, what a strange way to call `and` and `or` :)

Comment: Another small question, if I may.  The result list ends with 02:59:00 despite the condition being `lte` and not `lt`.  What gives?

Comment: You're welcome. For your question, Should you have results between 02:59:00 and 03:00:00 ?

Answer (score 6):

I believe, you want something like:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "time": {
                            "gt": "2014-11-01T00:00:00Z",
                            "lte": "2014-11-01T03:00:00Z"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "field1:value1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Elasticsearch doesn't seem to let you chain multiple things together under a single "query" tag.

(Sorry about formatting, I can't make `{` look pretty and lined up.)

Comment: No problem. I just started some work with elasticsearch myself, so getting to grips with the same way of doing thing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Per the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_ranges), it's possible to do this now with just the `query_string` param as below:

```
{
  "query_string": {
    "query": "field1:value1 AND time:[2014-11-01T00:00:00Z TO 2014-11-01T03:00:00Z]"
  }
}
```